# d3.js selecting key with a space in the name

Tags: javascript, d3.js

part of the data I pass into my d3 graph looks like this.

```
 {
                    "Type": "Streets",
                    "Open": "515910",
                    "Due Soon": "88669",
                    "Overdue": "162642",
                    "Closed": "801993"
                },
```

How would I select select a key like `Due Soon` as it has a space in it, where typically I select objects from data (d) like this  d.Type , d.Open , how would I select d.Due Soon as this will be seen as two variables by javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object["Due Soon"]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

`d['due soon']` should work also